# Wordpress menu issues

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress theme that has this setting in its Themes.Header file where it takes ALL my pages and uses that as the menu. No way to edit the menu except deleting the actual pages in wordpress.

I found the code for the menu can anyone explain to me how i may make this use a normal menu?

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
        <li class="<?php if (is_home()) { ?>current_page_item<?php } else { ?>page_item<?php } ?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried editing your menu from here wp-admin appearance>menu, I think u have not created any menu thr so it automatically call all the page, go and create new menu and add ur desired page in menu

regarding the code u have pastes It's just for home page url

Comment: i know wordpress quite well been using for 3 years. and i tried that. like i said. in the Themes.header file that code is telling the theme to use the pages as the menu.

Comment: wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1') ur depth is set to 1 means it'll show child pages too try to comment that code and add register new menu in function.php and call it from thr, I think u might know how to create menu and use css to style them